# Imageview's image not set in bindingadapter in databinding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am trying to set the image in image view via a binding adapter. I am passing two-parameter, an icon, and a condition.
I have logged in to check whether the function is called or not. The function is called but the image view is not setup the image.

Code of imageview:

```
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_remove"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        isEntryField="@{group_field_wtih_values.is_entry_field}"
        icon="@{group_field_wtih_values.is_entry_field ? ResourceProvider.enabledRemoveBtn:ResourceProvider.disabledRemoveBtn}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
```

Code of bindingadapter:

```
 @BindingAdapter({"icon","isEntryField"})
public static void setImageResource(ImageView imageView,Integer icon,boolean isEntryField){
    Log.e("setImageResources",String.valueOf(icon));
    if (!isEntryField)
        imageView.setImageDrawable(imageView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(icon));
}
```

Comment: Could you verify if "icon" variable has the correct value inside the setImageResource mehod? :)

Comment: thanks @rguzman ..i checked...no they are not corect value...as you can see in my code `icon="@{group_field_wtih_values.is_entry_field ? ResourceProvider.enabledRemoveBtn:ResourceProvider.disabledRemoveBtn}"' ` have a conditional statement. Image is not loading if I use it..but I try to pass only image variable like in this case `ResourceProvider.ic...` and that is working..

Comment: So, instead of "group_field_wtih_values.is_entry_field ? ResourceProvider.enabledRemoveBtn:ResourceProvider.disabledRemoveBtn", you can do something like this, "group_field_wtih_values.is_entry_field ? R.drawable.icon_x:R.drawable.icon_y" and inside the method "imageView.setImageResource(icon)". Also, try to change "Integer" to "@DrawableRes int icon" or just"int icon".

Comment: i have done it...not worked..same value is getting whether I used R package or ResourceProvider